# How to bind a keyboard shortcut to the "Source Control > Rename..." action?

Tags: git, matlab, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, file-rename

This question deals with the Git integration that is available in MATLAB (R2020a, Win10).

When editing files that belong to a Git repository through the MATLAB IDE, it is possible to perform various [VCS actions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-source-control-with-projects.html) using a "Source Control" context menu when right clicking a tracked file:

[image]

I am using the "Rename..." function quite a lot, but unfortunately there's no keyboard shortcut associated with it, which is inconvenient. Typically, keyboard bindings are defined in the "Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts" menu, but the only "Rename..." action is associated with the Genome Browser tool (which is not what I want):

[image]

> **Question:** How can I bind a keyboard shortcut of my choice (e.g., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) to the aforementioned action?

I suspect this may be possible using the UI's java interface, but I haven't tried this yet.